# C# - Misusing static variables

Tags: c#, oop

I have a class like below (refactored for purpose) in a PR and one of the seniors who is now on holiday stated I was misusing static variables and I should pass variables from method to method.

```
class Class {
  static int dataPool;
  
  // the below methods are called cyclicly for the duration of the application, 
  // xxxx times, First method is called and then Second is called, 
  // over and over
  public static void First()
  {
    // at the start, reads dataPool count to do computation
    // at the end, set dataPool count based on computation
  }

  public static void Second()
  {
    // at the start, read dataPool count to do some computation
    // at the end, set dataPool count based on computation
  }
}
```

I want to understand why using variables like the above is 'bad' to learn. Can anyone explain please?

Comment: We can not answer this. This example is beyond advisable - it is too abstract from naming and anything. This may or may not be an abuse of local variables, depending on many factors all of whom are not here. Also, this is a site for programming issues - code review has a separate site (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Not sure what your asking, you cannot access the non-static dataPool inside a static method ...

Comment: Sorry, updated I meant "static"

Comment: `static` *field* (`dataPool`) is shared between all threads, calles etc. So the questions are: Is implementation of `First` and `Second` are thread safe? Is it safe to call, say, `First() First() Second() First() Second() Second()`, will `dataPool` be still consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to understand why using variables like the above is 'bad' to learn. Can anyone explain please?

Main reasons:

- It means your code is no-longer re-entrant.
- It means your code is no-longer thread-safe (or even *less* thread-safe) and cannot run concurrently.
- It means your code has state in unexpected places (see: *Principle of Least Astonishment*).
- It means your code will perform poorly in a multi-threaded system (even if it's strictly single-threaded and without reentrancy) as having mutable static-state means your compiler cannot optimize your program's use of memory because it cannot guarantee thread ownership of data. Cache coherency is *expensive*.
- It means you **cannot** correctly unit-test your code (using the strict definition of "unit test", not Visual Studio's).
- It means the JIT compiler cannot optimize your program as much as it could if it could otherwise because reasoning about the lifetime of static state is very difficult.
- It means your code could be broken if another function or thread decides to mutate your static state without you knowing it.